# Flutter: How to inherit the constructor of a widget through extends

Tags: flutter

I want to write a simple Customizedtextfieldwidget that is inherited from textfieldwidget with some preset attribute.

For example:

```
class CustomizedTextFieldWidget extends TextFormField {
  CustomizedTextFieldWidget() : super(
    textAlign: TextAlign.right
  );
}
```

I want to use the widget in the same way as TextFormField, that inherited all attribute of TextFormField like:

```
CustomizedTextFieldWidget(decoration: InputDecoration(...))
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Update:

Because I am going to reuse the widget a lot and I would like to make my code a bit cleaner, is there any way to export the attribute setting of the TextFieldWidget, such that:

```
TextFieldWidget(
  setting: Mysetting,
   //usual attribute afterward
)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
class CustomizedTextFieldWidget extends TextFormField {
  CustomizedTextFieldWidget({InputDecoration decoration}) : super(
    decoration: decoration,
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it mean that if I have other attribute I wanted to use, only way to do that is to put them as part of the input of constructor in my customized widget class?
Because I am going to reuse the widget a lot and I would like to make my code a bit cleaner, are there any way to like export the attribute setting of the TextFieldWidget, such that:
TextFieldWidget(
  setting: Mysetting,
   //usual attribute afterward
)

Comment: it is the only way I know so far

Comment: Thank you so much still, your solution still helps. <3

Comment: In general, composition is preferred to inheritance for Widgets, because the elements that must be provided to the constructor could increase over time and your subclass would become invalid or incompatible.